# Fourier transform of $e^{-at}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I already figured out FT of e^(-at^2), but this one seems to be too hard for me. I found that it should be 1/(a+i*p), but why?

Edit: Sorry, new to the page and didnt undestand the rules that I need to show effort. Apologizes. I tried to calculate it for $t>0$ and $a>0$. I got
$$F = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at}e^{-ipt}dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{t(-a-ip)}dt = \left[\frac{e^{t(-a-ip)}}{-a-ip}\right]_0 = \frac{1}{a+ip}$$
Thanks, Andrew

Comment: How did you "figure" the answer? You must have done some calculations to obtain that result, but then why would you not present those? On this site, you should show your own efforts before expecting others to help.

Comment: What? The answer to it is everywhere so why would I share it here???

Comment: If the answer to it is everywhere, why bother asking us?

Comment: to this e^(-at^2) Kenny, not this e^(-at)

Comment: The answer to $e^{-a t}$ is aswell everywhere or at least in every FT table you can find. What especially @A.Pongrácz pointed out is that you did not showed us how you got your answer $\frac1{a+i\cdot p}$ and therefore we cannot determine where you went wrong or what you really did. So just include your own calculation of arriving at $\frac1{a+i\cdot p}$ as FT of $e^{-a t}$.

Comment: sorry everyone, editted

Comment: Looks like you got the right answer, so what are you actually asking? what's the problem?

Comment: When computing a Fourier transform you integrate over $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$. By integrating over just $\int_{0}^\infty$ what you are computing is more of a Laplace transform (for $s = ip$).

Answer (score 2):

Actually the function $e^{-at}$ does not *have* a Fourier transform - it's not integrable, not even a tempered distribution. What you've calculated here is the Fourier transform of the function $f$ defined by $$f(t)=\begin{cases}e^{-at},&(t\ge0),\\0,&(t<0).\end{cases}$$